# Subquery is not working on mysql (version 5.7.18)

Tags: mysql

This query is not working on mysql v 5.7.18 .

But this query was working perfectly in the past version of mysql (5.5.46)

```
SELECT car_id FROM (
                    SELECT car_id ,
                      CASE  WHEN ( unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE( car_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))  > unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE( '2017-03-15 13:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))
                                  || unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE( '2017-03-09 17:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )) > unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE(  car_to , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))
                                  || unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE( '2017-03-15 13:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )) < unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE( '2017-03-09 17:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))
                                  || unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE(  car_to, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )) < unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE(  car_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))
                                )  THEN 0
                    ELSE 1 END as intersect_time
                    FROM car_booking_master
                    WHERE state = '1'
                    GROUP BY car_id
                    HAVING intersect_time =  1
                    ) AS virtual
```

On the new mysql version I am getting this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'virtual
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 15
```

Comment: Did you post the entire query?  I don't see `LIMIT` appearing anywhere, yet it appears in the error message.

Comment: yes this is complete getting limit text in error output

Comment: The outer query does not make any sense to me.  If you already aggregated by `car_id`, then why wrap with another select?  By the way, your subquery also has a problem because you are selecting non aggregate columns in the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Than how this query is working on mysql  5.5.46

Comment: I think I know what is wrong, it's your invalid `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem on mysql version was the keyword I am using "virtual" . 
After using "v" in place of "virtual" query is working fine

Comment: `working fine` is a relative thing.  Your `GROUP BY` has a logical problem, so no, it isn't fine.  If you had done a better job of explaining what the query is trying to do, you might have gotten back a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to give your subquery a alias, you should remove `AS` in your last line.

Comment: I think `AS` is optional in MySQL.

Comment: still error is same after removing "AS".  And it was working on past version of mysql

Comment: The problem was with keyword "virtual"